# Ionic cordova social sharing plugin always returning true

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Cordova social  sharing plugin(Facebook) is always returning true in .then(function(res)). Before posting its showing true.If we cancel the share posting then its also returning true. .then(function()) returning true before posting.Please anybody help for that.Its very urgent.Need code help.

```
$scope.share_fb = function(message, logo, url){
$cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaFacebook(message, '', url)
    .then(function (result) {
    var link=site_url+"share_point?id="+user_id;
                                        $http.post(link).success(function(res){
                                        $scope.load_profile();
                                        });
                                    $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){});
    }, function(error) {
                         alert("Cannot share on Facebook");
                     })
}
$cordovaSocialSharing.canShareVia("facebook", message, logo, url).then(function(result) {
        $scope.share_fb(message, logo, url);


                }, function(error) {
                    alert("Cannot share on Facebook");
                });
```

Comment: Plz add some code here

Comment: Hi guys anybody help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen here: [similar question + answer on the Ionic forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordovasocialsharing-cansharevia-instagram-not-working-in-android/43403/7)

```
var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid(); 


if(isIOS) {
    $cordovaSocialSharing.canShareVia("instagram").then(function(result) {  
        $scope.canShareInstagram  = true; 
    }, function() {
        $scope.canShareInstagram  = false;
    });               
} else {
   if(isAndroid) {
    $cordovaAppAvailability.check('com.instagram.android')
        .then(function() {
            $scope.canShareInstagram  = true;
        }, function () {
            $scope.canShareInstagram  = false;
        });            
   } 
}
```

It's a workaround that should prove just as satisfactory.